# Control+Page up/down for moving tabs not working on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension

`Google Chrome: Version 99.0.4844.51 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

From the recent update, I found that when I am reading a PDF document (if I click anywhere in the document) on chrome, `Control+Page up/down` to move between tabs no longer works. Instead, it interprets as usual `Page up/down` that scrolls the PDF.

Is there a good way (an extension perhaps) to get the old behaviour back?

Comment: It's a [bug](https://crbug.com/1038918), fixed in Chrome 100. The workaround is to disable `chrome://flags/#pdf-unseasoned`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!!!!!!!!!
It was super annoying!